# Reloading workers state from disk in FastAPI

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, fastapi

Reading through existing questions, I am still not sure if it is feasible to reload state of **all** Worker processes in FastAPI.

Bellow is a simplified app sketch:

```
some_dict = load_data(path)
server = Server(some_dict)
app = FastAPI()  
app.include_router(server.router)
uvicorn.run(app, ...)
```

A server:

```
class Server:
   def __init__(self, some_dict: Dict[str, ...]):
       self.router = APIRouter()
       self.router.add_api_route("/bar", self.bar, methods=["POST"])
       self.some_dict = some_dict 

def bar(self, text: str):
    pass
```

Is there a way to periodically reload this dictionary from the disk so that change is visible to all workers and all threads in a safe manner? With or without FastAPI built-ins.

Does FastAPI background task run in **each** worker or in a single(separate) process?

I would like to avoid reloading server, rather build separate dict instance and replace reference as bellow:

```
# this should be the only place to update state of some_dict
class Server:
    def reload(self,..):
        data = load_from_disk()
        some_dict = build_from_data(data)
        self.some_dict = some_dict
```

What would be the simplest possible example to solve this?
It is okay if workers are briefly out of sync

The value object is complex, and while it could be put in Redis I am looking if this is first doable from FastAPI.

Comment: Yeah, that'd be feasible. `pickle` files can contain most Python data, and if you want a more transparent way to store them, I can recommend the `diskcache` library from PyPI.

Comment: Thanks for the comment AKX. Would be grateful for a simple example of how periodic task could be scheduled in FastAPI to ensure that all worker processes see the changed value of: some_dict :)
Pickle is okay, or just a .yml file that would be parsed into dict in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of periodically reloading your dict, you might want to make it check whether it needs to reload data from disk whenever you access it.

I didn't test this, but the theory is there...

```
import os
import pickle
import time
from collections.abc import Mapping


class PeriodicallyReloadedReadonlyDict(Mapping):
    def __init__(self, filename: str, max_age: float = 60.0):
        self.filename = filename
        self.max_age = max_age
        self.last_loaded = None
        self.last_mtime = None
        self.state = None

    def _ensure_loaded(self):
        if self.state is None or time.time() - self.last_loaded > self.max_age:
            if not os.path.exists(self.filename):
                self.state = {}
            else:
                mtime = os.path.getmtime(self.filename)
                if mtime > self.last_loaded:
                    with open(self.filename, "rb") as f:
                        self.state = pickle.load(f)
                self.last_mtime = mtime
            self.last_loaded = time.time()

    def save(self) -> None:
        with open(self.filename, "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(self.state, f)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        self._ensure_loaded()
        return self.state[key]

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        self._ensure_loaded()
        return len(self.state)

    def __iter__(self):
        self._ensure_loaded()
        return iter(self.state)
```

Comment: With this example, whenever worker reads dict it would use this wrapper which would reload as needed?
No need for background scheduling in this case right?
Might require lock on methods since worker delegates task to a thread pool for execution, multiple threads could execute this.

Comment: Sure, you could add a lock in the inner part of `_ensure_loaded` (but it's pretty much harmless if you don't, it might just cause extra reloads). But yeah, `self.some_dict = PeriodicallyReloadedReadonlyDict("my_state.pickle")` and then use it as you like.

Comment: The only challenge could be loading multiple large dicts in ram and blow up memory but this should be inspirational :)

Comment: Then you'll want to use something else for state, maybe SQLite...